# PHP problemas al pasar variables por URL

Tags: php, html, sql, variables, url

Estoy aprendiendo PHP y se me ocurrió hacer un pequeño formulario con un *input text* y un botón *submit* para enviar una consulta SQL que lo que debía hacer es cargarme en el input el valor de la última fabricación realizada. Pero no hay manera.

Os pongo el código de los 2 ficheros, a ver si alguien me puede echar una mano.

Fichero: `ATRAS.php` contiene el formulario que envía la consulta y debería recibir en el input text el valor sel númerofabriación:

```
<body>
<?php echo $_GET['variable'] ?>  
  
<form name="atras" action="Actions/RetrocederRegistro.php">
    <label>FABRICACION:  </label>
    <input type="text" name="NUMEROFABRICACION" value='$fabricacion'/>
    <INPUT type="submit" name="ATRAS" value="ATRAS" />
    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Fichero `RetrocederRegistro.php` contiene lo necesario para realizar la conexión y la consulta y el envío por URL de la variable con el número de la última producción

```
<?php
include ("../Includes/miconexion.php");

$consulta = "SELECT MAX(NumeroFabricacion) FROM ferrico";
$resultado = mysqli_query($miconexion, $consulta) or die("No se puede ejecutar la consulta");
$columna = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
$fabricacion =  $columna[0] - 1;
mysqli_close($miconexion);

echo "<a href='ATRAS.php?variable=fabricacion>";

?>
```

Comment: En PHP tienes:`$_GET['variable']` y en el HTML tienes ` <input name="NUMEROFABRICACION" />` Lo que tu has llamado como `variable` es el name del input al cual tu has llamado `NUMEROFABRICACION`, ambos nombres deben ser iguales, así que lo debes cambiar en el PHP o en el input.

Comment: ... *y se me ocurrío hacer un pequeño formulario con un input text y un botón submit para enviar una consulta SQL que lo que debía hacer es cargarme en el input el valor de la última fabricación realizada.* Hay una forma más moderna y más transparente de hacer esto. Consiste en usas Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. Cuando se cargue la página, envías una petición Ajax para que busque el último valor y te lo cargue donde lo necesites, sin necesidad de ninguna intervención del usuario.

Comment: Estoy a cero de conocimientos de Ajax y lo que preciso es poder moverme entre los registros.

Comment: Con la última respuesta obtenida lo que me hace es ponerme en el input text, $fabricación, pero no el valor de la variable $fabricacion.

Comment: hola, ¿ es NumeroFabricacion un número consecutivo, sin saltos ? porque si no es así el máximo -1 te  devolverá el valor anterior en número pero no necesariamente tiene que existir ese valor si por ejemplo por alguna razón se ha borrado el anterior que en ese caso no existiría

Answer (score 0):

Basado en tu código, no estás regresando el valor de fabricación, porque no estas invocando la variable, recuerda debe empezar con `$`

```
echo "<a href='ATRAS.php?variable=fabricacion>";
```

deberia ser:

```
echo "<a href='ATRAS.php?variable=$fabricacion>";
```

en lo personal me gusta más hacer algo como esto:

```
$regresar="<a href='ATRAS.php?variable=".$fabricacion.">";
echo $regresar;
```

Pero es cuestión de gustos, yo lo hago porque me gusta enviar solo una variable a pantalla, espero te ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Lo que visualizo así en el inputext es $fabricación y no su valor.